# Explicit broadcasting of variable batch-size tensor

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to implement a custom Keras `Layer` in Tensorflow 2.0RC and need to concatenate a `[None, Q]` shaped tensor onto a `[None, H, W, D]` shaped tensor to produce a `[None, H, W, D + Q]` shaped tensor. It is assumed that the two input tensors have the same batch size even though it is not known beforehand. Also, none of H, W, D, and Q are known at write-time but are evaluated in the layer's `build` method when the layer is first called. The issue that I'm experiencing is when broadcasting the `[None, Q]` shaped tensor up to a `[None, H, W, Q]` shaped tensor in order to concatenate.

Here is an example of trying to create a Keras `Model` using the Functional API that performs variable-batch broadcasting from shape `[None, 3]` to shape `[None, 5, 5, 3]`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as kl
import numpy as np

x = tf.keras.Input([3])  # Shape [None, 3]
y = kl.Reshape([1, 1, 3])(x)  # Need to add empty dims before broadcasting
y = tf.broadcast_to(y, [-1, 5, 5, 3])  # Broadcast to shape [None, 5, 5, 3]

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)

print(model(np.random.random(size=(8, 3))).shape)
```

Tensorflow produces the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Dimension -1 must be >= 0
```

And then when I change `-1` to `None` it gives me:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 5, 5, 3]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

How can I perform the specified broadcasting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the dynamic shape of `y` to determine the batch size. The dynamic shape of a tensor `y` is given by `tf.shape(y)` and is a tensor op representing the shape of `y` evaluated at runtime. The modified example demonstrates this by selecting between the old shape, `[None, 1, 1, 3]`, and the new shape using [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/where).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as kl
import numpy as np

x = tf.keras.Input([3])  # Shape [None, 3]
y = kl.Reshape([1, 1, 3])(x)  # Need to add empty dims before broadcasting
# Retain the batch and depth dimensions, but broadcast along H and W
broadcast_shape = tf.where([True, False, False, True],
                           tf.shape(y), [0, 5, 5, 0])
y = tf.broadcast_to(y, broadcast_shape)  # Broadcast to shape [None, 5, 5, 3]

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)

print(model(np.random.random(size=(8, 3))).shape)
# prints: "(8, 5, 5, 3)"
```

References:

["TensorFlow: Shapes and dynamic dimensions"](https://blog.metaflow.fr/shapes-and-dynamic-dimensions-in-tensorflow-7b1fe79be363)